# Structural pattern matching in Python 3.10 "NameError: name 'match' is not defined"

Tags: python, structural-pattern-matching

I'm excited to try the new structural pattern matching in Python 3.10 but the commands are not recognized. I tried on both 3.10.0 and 3.10.4:

```
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> match
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'match' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't defined what ```match``` is.   Did you mean to want to ```import re``` and use ```re.match()```?

Comment: @ewong No, they meant to use https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/

Comment: @mkrieger1  Ah thanks for the clarification.  Learn something new today.

Answer (score 4):

The specification of the `match` statement ([PEP 634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#the-match-statement)) says:

> The match and case keywords are soft keywords, i.e. they are not reserved words in other grammatical contexts (including at the start of a line if there is no colon where expected). This implies that they are recognized as keywords when part of a match statement or case block only, and are allowed to be used in all other contexts as variable or argument names.

This means that if you try to evaluate an expression that is just `match`, it will not be treated as a `match` statement, but as a variable called `match`, which isn't defined in your case (no pun intended).

Try writing a complete `match` statement.

Comment: Thanks this works! A complete match statement is required. Part of what was confusing me was that I am using in PyCharm Community Edition and the match/case keywords are not recognized in Pycharm 2021.3.1 but they are recognized in the latest version 2020.3.3.